# Neo4j Spatial- two nodes created for every spatially indexed node

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j 1.8.2 with Neo4j Spatial 0.9 for 1.8.2 (http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.9-neo4j-1.8.2/)

Followed the example code from here http://architects.dzone.com/articles/neo4jcypher-finding-football with one change- instead of SpatialIndexProvider.SIMPLE_WKT_CONFIG, I used SpatialIndexProvider.SIMPLE_POINT_CONFIG_WKT

Everything works fine until you execute the following query:

```
START n=node:stadiumsLocation('withinDistance:[53.489271,-2.246704, 5.0]') 
RETURN n.name, n.wkt;
```

n.name is null. When I explored the graph, I found this data:

```
Node[80]{lon:-2.20024,lat:53.483,id:79,gtype:1,bbox:-2.20024,53.483,-2.20024,53.483]}      
Node[168]{lon:-2.29139,lat:53.4631,id:167,gtype:1,bbox:-2.29139,53.4631,-2.29139,53.4631]}
```

For Node 80 returned, it looks like this is the node created for the spatial record, which contains a property id:79. Node 79 is the actual stadium record from the example.

As per the source of [IndexProviderTest](https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/IndexProviderTest.java), the comments
 *//We not longer need this as the node we get back already a 'Real' node
// Node node = db.getNodeById( (Long) spatialRecord.getProperty( "id" ) );*
 seem to indicate that this feature isn't available in the version I am using.

My question is, what is the recommended way to use withinDistance with other match conditions? There are a couple of other conditions to be fulfilled but I can't seem to get a handle on the actual node to actually match them. 
Should I explicitly create relations? Not use Cypher and use the core API to do a traversal? Split the queries?

Comment: Lemme try to recreate this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

a) Use GeoPipline.startNearestNeighborLatLonSearch to get a starting set of nodes, supply to subsequent Cypher query to do matching/filtering on other properties
b) Since my lat/longs are common across many entities [using centroid of an area], I can create a relation from the spatial node to all entities that are located in that area and then use one Cypher query such as:
START n=node:stadiumsLocation('withinDistance:[53.489271,-2.246704, 5.0]')
MATCH (n)<-[:LOCATED_IN]-(something)
WHERE something.someProp=5
RETURN something

As advised by Peter, went with option b. 
Note though, there is no way to get the spatially indexed node back so that you can create relations from it. Had to do a withinDistance query for 0.0 distance.

Answer (score 0):

can you execute the enhanced testcase I did at https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/2803093d544f56d7dfe8f1d122e049fa73489d8a/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/IndexProviderTest.java#L199 ? It shows how to find a location, and traverse with cypher to the next node.

Comment: Tried on 1.8.2 and I did get results but not the ones expected. In the example above, I am actually looking for nodes with IDs 79 and 167. With match p=n--m, m is a bunch of nodes but none of them are ID's 79 and 167 (they all seem to be location nodes and not the actual node that contains the non-spatial properties)